# CSS slider with arrows using animation

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to achieve a CSS only slider.
When `hover`ing left and right arrows, the slider has to *slide*. Of course.

I tried something using `animation-play-state`, `animation-fill-mode` (to keep the positions) and `animation-direction` but I'm not able to fully make it work.

- Starting with `animation-play-state: paused`, `hover`ing the arrows changes it to `running`.
- On `hover` of the right arrow, everything is fine. We can hover, leave, hover again.
- But, as soon as I `hover` the left arrow (that changes the `animation-direction` to `reverse`), it's broken.

**Simplified snippet**:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

.arrows {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrows:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow-l {
  left: 0;
}

.arrow-r {
  right: 0;
}

.sliding {
  height: 160px;
  width: 2000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49.9%, gray 50.1%);
  animation: slide 2s linear;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.arrows:hover~.sliding {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.arrow-l:hover~.sliding {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-1500px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrows arrow-l">[ ← ]</div>
  <div class="arrows arrow-r">[ → ]</div>
  <div class="sliding"></div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening, and correct this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: changing the direction will change the whole animation and will not simply change the current direction by keeping the current state

Comment: Hey @TemaniAfif, thanks for that. Do you know about a way to correct it?

Comment: When your animation is stopped, its stopped. It will not start again by reversing the direction. When you put it on infinite, it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/eL6ygf51/8/ But of course, then the animation will be infinite, so you would have to find a way to adjust that.

Answer (score 9):

The main issue here is that changing the direction will keep the current state of the animation BUT it will consider the new direction. Let's take an easy example:

Suppose you have an animation from `left:0` to `left:100%`. If you first run the animation untill `left:80%` and then you change the direction to reverse you will have `left:20%`!

**Why?**

Because with the default direction you reached the 80% (`left:80%`) of the animation and 80% of the same animation with reverse direction is simply `left:20%`.

Hover on **reverse** and you will see that the position of the box is jumping to switch to the new state considering the new direction. It's obvious when the animation ends and you will be switching between the first and last state:

```css
.sliding {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  left:0%;
  position:relative;
  animation:slide 5s linear forwards;
  animation-play-state:paused;
}
.arrows {
  margin:20px;
}

.arrow-r:hover~.sliding {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.arrow-l:hover~.sliding {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrows arrow-r">move normal</div>
  <div class="arrows arrow-l">reverse !!</div>
  <div class="sliding"></div>
</div>
```

There is no fix for this since it's the default behavior of animation, but instead you can rely on transition to obtain a similar effect. The trick is to play with the duration that you increase/decrease to create the needed effect.

Here is an idea:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

.arrows {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrows:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow-l {
  left: 0;
}

.arrow-r {
  right: 0;
}

.sliding {
  height: 160px;
  width: 2000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49.9%, gray 50.1%);
  transition:all 2000s linear; /*This will block the current state*/
}
.arrow-r:hover ~ .sliding {
  transform: translate(-1500px, 0);
  transition:all 2s;
}

.arrow-l:hover ~ .sliding {
  transform: translate(0px, 0);
  transition:all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrows arrow-l">[ ← ]</div>
  <div class="arrows arrow-r">[ → ]</div>
  <div class="sliding"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, reverse is not animated, is this intended?

Comment: @Sirence yes it's intended ;) to show how the direction affect the state and make it clear

Comment: Could you post the working version as well? I am also really interested in this question.

Comment: I think there is a small issue with your solution: Let's say we scroll for 10% to the right, it will take the "correct" amount of time, but then when we scroll back on the left, it takes 10 times the "correct" amount of time. ⋅⋅⋅ I don't know if there is any way to correct that. Maybe there is an easing function that would make it less noticeable ?

Comment: @TakitIsy Yes because the default is ease, I have changed to linear, it should be better

Comment: I think it's gonna be more noticeable with `linear`.

Comment: @TakitIsy Ok I got it, will think about a way ... but I guess playin with easing is your only solution

Comment: From the initial state: when we hover [ → ] for 0.2s, we're at 10% of the slider. Then, we hover [ ← ] and it takes 2s to go back to 0%.

Comment: @TakitIsy well I didn't find any pure CSS solution for this ... I think we cannot do better with CSS. You can consider a bounty if you feel that we can still do something but I don't think so.