# Proper way of reversing an animation with Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a pretty straightforward example here where I apply an animation through JS to grow my inner div. However, upon trying to reverse the animation with JS, I am finding it does not transition; rather, it suddenly snaps back to the original state.

Example:

```js
const grow = document.querySelector('.grow');
const reverse = document.querySelector('.reverse');
const inner = document.querySelector('.inner');


grow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inner.classList.add('grow');
})

//things I've tried

// reverse.addEventListener('click', function() {
//   inner.classList.add('reverse');
// })

reverse.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inner.style.animationDirection = 'reverse';
})
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
}

.grow {
  animation: grow forwards 1s ease-in-out;
}

.reverse {
  animation: grow reverse 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    height: 52px;
  }
  
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <button class="grow">Grow</button>
    <button class="reverse">Reverse</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening, and how I can revert the transition back smoothly without adding a separate keyframe labeled 'shrink'?

Comment: probably a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221219/css-slider-with-arrows-using-animation ... you will find the explanation, and generally using transition is the way to go here

Comment: Thanks, I saw that transitions would be ideal, however I want to specifically use key frames and animation to make a more controlled animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because both `.grow` and `.reverse` attached to `.inner` and that's messing things up. You have to remove `.grow` before adding `.reverse`. However, this time when you remove `.grow` animation, the div's height will decrease to `52px` again, so you must keep its height before you apply `.reverse`. However(again), you need to decrease `.inner`'s height after running `.reverse`, otherwise it won't lose its height. So you can do something like this:

```
reverse.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inner.classList.remove('grow');
  inner.style.height = '100%';

  // You need setTimeout() idk why
  setTimeout(function() {
    inner.classList.add('reverse');
    inner.style.height = '52px';
  }, 10);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `animationDirection` property only has an effect on infinite animations ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationdirection.asp)), so you might still want to consider using `shrink`.

Your code with infinite animations:

```js
const grow = document.querySelector('.grow');
const reverse = document.querySelector('.reverse');
const inner = document.querySelector('.inner');


grow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inner.classList.add('grow');
})

//things I've tried

// reverse.addEventListener('click', function() {
//   inner.classList.add('reverse');
// })

reverse.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inner.style.animationDirection = 'reverse';
})
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
}

.grow {
  animation: grow forwards 1s infinite;
}

.reverse {
  animation: grow reverse 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    height: 52px;
  }
  
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <button class="grow">Grow</button>
    <button class="reverse">Reverse</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Shrink solution:

```js
const grow = document.querySelector('.grow');
const reverse = document.querySelector('.reverse');
const inner = document.querySelector('.inner');


grow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inner.classList.add('grow');
})

//things I've tried

 reverse.addEventListener('click', function() {
   inner.classList.add('reverse');
 })
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 52px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
}

.grow {
  animation: grow forwards 1s ease-in-out;
}

.reverse {
  animation: shrink forwards 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    height: 52px;
  }
  
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  from {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  to {
    height: 52px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <button class="grow">Grow</button>
    <button class="reverse">Reverse</button>
  </div>
</div>
```