# CSS animation-direction not working as I would have expected

Tags: css, css-animations, css-animation-direction

> **N.B.** With the (more complex) setup I'm actually working with I can't use `CSS Transitions`. I recognise that `CSS Transitions` would be a
> perfectly good solution in the example below.

I'm having a little trouble with

```
animation-direction: reverse
```

which I've never used before but doesn't seem to be running the way I might have expected it to.

The easiest solution to my problem would be to write two CSS `@keyframes` animations and use one or the other.

But for the sake of economy and elegance I would like to use **a single animation** and play it forwards or backwards.

This example below shows the effect I'm trying to achieve.

When the page loads, pressing *either button* will fire the intended animation.

However, after one button is pushed, **the animation no longer runs** and only the end-frame of the forwards or reverse animation is displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Working Example:**

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');
const buttonOutbound = document.querySelector('button.outboundButton');
const buttonReturn = document.querySelector('button.returnButton');


buttonOutbound.addEventListener('click', () => {   
  square.className = 'square';   
  square.classList.add('outbound');
}, false);

buttonReturn.addEventListener('click', () => {   
  square.className = 'square';
  square.classList.add('return');
}, false);
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1);
}

.square.outbound {
  animation: animateSquare 1s linear normal forwards;
}

.square.return {
  animation: animateSquare 1s linear reverse forwards;
}

@keyframes animateSquare {
  
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
    transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<button type="button" class="outboundButton">Outbound animation</button>
<button type="button" class="returnButton">Return animation</button>
```

Comment: related to understand what is happening: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51221329/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333022/8620333

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif. The key for me was when I realised that the `.outbound` class alone was maintaining the presentational state of `.square` after the animation had completed - and it was doing so solely on the basis of `animation-fill-mode` value. Consequently, as soon as I removed the `.outbound` class, the single thing holding the presentational state in place... wasn't there anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a think about this away from my laptop screen and realised that... what was missing from my original set up was **one additional static class**, describing the presentational state of `.square` *after* the `.outbound` animation has run:

```
.square.outbounded {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.5);
}
```

(**N.B.** *There's no need for a corresponding static class, describing the state of `.square` after the `.return` animation has run, since the presentational state that class would describe is already described in the initial styles of `.square`*)

---

**Working Example** *(with* `.outbounded` *class added)*

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');
const buttonOutbound = document.querySelector('button.outboundButton');
const buttonReturn = document.querySelector('button.returnButton');


buttonOutbound.addEventListener('click', () => {

  square.className = 'square outbound';
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    square.classList.add('outbounded');
    square.classList.remove('outbound');
  }, 1000);
  
}, false);

buttonReturn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  square.className = 'square return';
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    square.classList.remove('return');
  }, 1000);
  
}, false);
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1);
}

.square.outbounded {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.5);
}

.square.outbound {
  animation: animateSquare 1s linear normal forwards;
}

.square.return {
  animation: animateSquare 1s linear reverse forwards;
}

@keyframes animateSquare {
  
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
    transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<button type="button" class="outboundButton">Outbound animation</button>
<button type="button" class="returnButton">Return animation</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser considers that animation as complete therefore it does not restart it in order to restart the animation you need to first remove the class and then re-add it however for the browser to recognize this change you need add a slight delay. Adding a setTimeout does the trick even if the timeout is 0 because js is single threaded.

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');
const buttonOutbound = document.querySelector('button.outboundButton');
const buttonReturn = document.querySelector('button.returnButton');


buttonOutbound.addEventListener('click', () => {   
  square.classList.remove('return');
  square.classList.remove('outbound'); 
  setTimeout(() => {
      square.classList.add('outbound');
  }, 0) 
}, false);

buttonReturn.addEventListener('click', () => {  
  square.classList.remove('return');
  square.classList.remove('outbound'); 
  setTimeout(() => {
      square.classList.add('return');
  }, 0) 
}, false);
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1);
}

.square.outbound {
  animation: animateSquare 1s linear normal forwards;
}

.square.return {
  animation: animateSquare 1s linear reverse forwards;
}

@keyframes animateSquare {
  
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
    transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<button type="button" class="outboundButton">Outbound animation</button>
<button type="button" class="returnButton">Return animation</button>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this attempt, @AhsanNaveed, but I'm not sure this works, does it (?)

Comment: @Rounin It seems to be working for me. What issue are you facing?

Comment: It animates the first time and doesn't animate after that.

Comment: Running the above code snippet on stack overflow (using the run code snippet button) seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: I gave it a spin in Brave and you're right - it's working much better there. (Albeit with a slight flash of styled content when the square is on the right and you press the right-hand button.) But - and I concede you probably haven't seen this - it's not working in Firefox.